# Php flush() browser doesn't show until some data stored into cache

Tags: php, flush

Well i have the following code:

```
<?php
while(1==1){
echo"piece<br>";
flush();
};
?>
```

The problem with this code is that the server doesn't send 1 line (`piece<br>`) at the time..
Sends 10 lines per flush or whatever..

I tried this `echo"piece<br>".str_repeat("\n",4096)`

but it doesn't work.I don't know what to do..
Any advice?

**Edit:** The code into [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734820/php-flush-function) but i can't write `html` :(

**Edit2:** I have [upload my script here](http://dap.ntua.gr/el/ssh.php). Works fine only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is this question really any different at all from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734820/php-flush-function

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, in the previous question i couldn't send anything(html) with flush()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having a problem with browser-side caching.  I've had this problem with Safari; using Firefox allowed me to see the data live.

If you see this with different browsers, then you may be hitting some server-side caching:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: only ie works well..
All other browsers have different results (10 lines / 15 lines /14 lines) (Firefox / Safari / Chrome) (The numbers are random). -- So how can i manage the cache of client?

Comment: I've done this by sending a lot of non-printables to flush the cache.

Comment: If i use `sleep(1)` works in Firefox!
But if i use the function then the server will be iddle for 1 second.Right?That's a problem
Can you write an example/code plz?